Children Bike Riding on Wet Sidewalk
Is it safe to allow my children to ride their bikes/scooters on a wet sidewalk?
I can't recall from my childhood whether wet sidewalks are more slippery.

Wet sidewalks are more slippery than dry sidewalks. But it's not what make them dangerous : it's the road next to it. The answer depends largely on the road and how busy it is, rather than the sidewalk itself. If your children never rode a bike on wet concrete, maybe it's better to introduce them to this on a safe place, not next to a busy road.

Wet sidewalks are slipperier than dry sidewalks, but rubber tires adhere to wet surfaces nearly as well as they adhere to dry surfaces.  Also consider that it's probably better for children to learn how to deal with rubber on wet surfaces when they're younger, so they can be more skillful at it than they would be if they only start when they're grown up.  As noted in this answer and the other comment, this means assuming that they will sometimes fall as they are learning, so making sure that they do it in a place where that is not going to put them in danger of worse than scrapes and bruises.

Children riding anything are going to fall off from time to time. As Astariul says in the comment, wet sidewalks are going to be a bit more slippery than dry sidewalks, but even on a perfectly dry sidewalk a child is going to come off sometimes, just like they will sometimes fall over if they are running.
Rather than worrying about the weather, think about what is going to happen when they come off. Bruises and scrapes are painful and inconvenient, but nothing more. Getting run over is another matter.
The main rule I would apply is not to use scooters and the like next to a busy road. A residential road with an occasional car is fine: drivers can see your child and should be driving slowly anyway. And the odds that your child falls into the road just as one is coming along is very low. The risk is minimal. On the other hand a busy road with cars driving close and fast is a much higher risk.
This assumes that your child has enough control to steer down the sidewalk without hitting anything, can stop the scooter in a reasonable distance, and will do as they are told if you shout "Stop" or "Slow down". If they can't do that then they are a danger to themselves and others no matter where they are using a scooter.

Thank you!  Thankfully, our sidewalk is a good distance from the road.
